# google-place autocomplete directive does not work when its used twice on a single page

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive

I am using a google-place directive to fill the location. The directive I am using is mentioned below:

```js
app.directive('googlePlaces', function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    replace:true,
    scope: {location:'='},
    template: '<input id="google_places_ac" name="google_places_ac" type="text" class="form-control area_input transition" />',
      link: function($scope, elm, attrs){
              if(attrs.city =='cities'){
                var options = {
                  types: ['(cities)'],
                  componentRestrictions: {country: 'IN'}
                }
              }
              else{
                var options = {
                  componentRestrictions: {country: 'IN'}
                }
              }
              var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#google_places_ac")[0], options);

              google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
               
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                if(attrs.city =='cities'){
                  $scope.location = $("#google_places_ac")[0].value + '"' +place.geometry.location.lat() + '"' + place.geometry.location.lng();
                }
                else{
                  $scope.location = place.geometry.location.lat() + ',' + place.geometry.location.lng();
                }
                $scope.$apply();
              });
      }
  };
});
```

```html
<google-places class="form-control location_field" location="location" city='cities' latlngs = "latlngs" ng-model="chosenPlace"></google-places>
```

But since I need to use it two times on a single page, the second directive does not work, i.e. it does not show autocomplete results. 
Could anyone please help me fix this issue. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not very familiar about angularjs but you can try creating two variable ID like `autocomplete1` and `autocomplete2`. With this, you will be able to initialize mutliple autocomplete without having to overwrite other automplete instances.For implementation purposes take a look in this SO [20416058](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20416328/5995040). For a more dynamic example try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28027112/5995040).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the reply.. I solved the issue, by replacing id(#google_places_ac) with 'elm[0]', where 'ele' is the element parameter passed in the link function, it refers to current element.